# Unable to serialize the session state because of Microsoft.Web.Services3.StateManager?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, serialization

There are many questions that are similar to this...but I'm not seeing how they have this specific issue:

I have a webservice which returns an error that starts with:

> Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and
>   'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects,
>   and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are
>   not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization
>   is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.

So, questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335444/unable-to-serialize-the-session-state-updated) mention to look for SerializationException, find out what is unable to be serialized, and make it serializable.  Sounds straightforward...but when I look for it, I find this:

> [SerializationException: Type 'Microsoft.Web.Services3.StateManager'
>   in Assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as
>   serializable.]

This confuses me...it sounds like it's actually trying to serialize the StateManager...is it just that it's hiding that something else inside is the StateManager is unable to be serialized?  If so, is there a way to find out what?  Or is the StateManager really supposed to be serializable for some reason?  (I suspect I'm not stating this very clearly...sorry...if you have questions, I'll do my best to answer them.)

One thing that I should also note is that we're using NCache as a session store provider, which seems like it could possibly be related in some way.  But it's not clear to me how that could cause what I'm seeing.

Comment: That is very strange.  Can you pin it down to a specific line of code?  Does it happen on every method call, or just certain ones?

Comment: Sadly, neither.  It happens only sometimes, and though it will happen several times in a row, it then goes away and we can't reproduce it after that, so it's been tough to track down.

Comment: I assume you've reviewed everything you're explicitly putting in session state or that uses session as a backing store, and you're not accidentally actually putting a StateManager into session.  (You'd probably see more of a pattern if you were doing that, actually). Since you say you're using NCache, I would start talking to that company and reviewing that company's forums, etc., if you haven't already.

Comment: @AnnL.   Actually the scenario in this case is that it's a webservice, and we're using it to send over a bunch of objects...I'll add some details to the question to highlight this.

Comment: Our issue has gone away.  The symptom was occuring because an item that .NET was serializing to be returned by the web service was not in a valid state, so the serialization would fail.  However, I'm still not sure why this strange error would be the result (and, as far as I can tell, a complete red herring...it certainly wasn't StateManager that couldn't be serialized...though I'm still not convinced that this wasn't partially due to NCache.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are serializing a custom object make sure to decorate the class with the  attribute.  Without this on any object that you put into the session state the serializer will fail.  You probably need to isolate the item you are storing and check it's properties and that it itself has that attribute.